# Linking the 'new' button on a Custom Object to a specific Opportunity Stage

Tags: opportunity, validation, administration

I'm learning Salesforce and I got stuck in a task here.

Basically I got a 'Quote' Custom Object that shows me the current Quotes for the current Opportunity.

But here's the catch: I want this 'New Quote' default button only to show up when the Stage is 'Approved'. Do I have to do it by a Validation Rule? I tried to find the solution but got no concrete answers to this specific task.

[image]

Hope you can assist me! Cheers <3

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can't hide this button, instead I can make the 'New Quote' only functional when the Stage is 'Approved'.

So I managed to find a beginning of a solution using a Validation Rule inside the 'Quote' object, but again I'm stuck at the code...

[image]